# Changing the application menu icon size

Tags: gnome

Hey there I am new to Ubuntu and I was working on to change the size of weird large-looking apps in the applications menu. Is there any way to do so?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

[image: it look's like this]

Comment: i am using ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Size can be controlled using theme editing but it will not increase number of rows or columns. You may try "more columns" gnome shell extension

Comment: Or use MATE which does permit resizing desktop icons easily

Comment: @unknown an others: question here is to change the size of the icons themselves, not the number of columns/rows, although the abandoned extension "Application View Columns by fawtytoo" at some point would reduce the size as well.

Comment: well changing the number of columns have resized the app icon size as stated by @vanadium byt it have also increased the number of icons by it's own .
If there had been any other way to have **only icon size changed** that would have been fine..